# Authenticate NestJS Application using Laravel Bearer Token

Tags: laravel, oauth, nestjs

I have a Laravel API system which utilises Laravel Passport as authentication and have just started a microservice using NestJS which we want to use the authentication within the Laravel API to issue the bearer token. How can I verify the bearer token within NestJS so I don't have to make a call to the Laravel API every time I want to create a function.
I have created the authentication function which take an email and password and receives a bearer token back which is fine, but when I try to verify the bearer token using the oauth secret I receive an unauthorised response every time.

Can this be done and how would I do it? Below is my current code:

```
import { Controller, Post, Get, Body, UseGuards, Req, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import axios from 'axios';

@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
    constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) { }

    @Post('authenticate')
    async authenticate(@Body() credentials: { email: string, password: string }) {
        return this.authenticateUser(credentials.email, credentials.password);
    }

    @Post('verify')
    async verify(@Req() req) {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        const clientSecret = process.env.auth_secret;
        return this.verifyToken(token, clientSecret);
    }

    @Get('me')
    async getUser(@Req() req) {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        const clientSecret = process.env.auth_secret;

        // Verify the token before making the request to the 'me' endpoint
        await this.verifyToken(token, clientSecret);

        try {
            // Make your authenticated request here
        } catch (error) {
            // Handle errors, e.g., log the error or return an error response.
            return error;
        }
    }

    async authenticateUser(email: string, password: string) {
        const response = await axios.post(process.env.connectBackendURL + '/api/users/authenticate?platform=app&verificationCode=null', {
            email,
            password,
        });
        return response.data;
    }


    async verifyToken(token, clientSecret) {
        try {
            // Verify the token using the client's secret key
            const decoded = await jwt.verify(token, clientSecret);

            // If verification is successful, 'decoded' will contain the token's payload
            return decoded;
        } catch (error) {
            // Handle errors, e.g., log the error or return an error response.
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Token verification failed');
        }
    }
}
```

Verify bearer token return invalid.

Comment: So what I understand is that you want to verify passport tokens in NestJS, right? If yes then it's not possible.